# React native touchablehighlight delete view inside

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm stuck on a strange issue :
I create a component class and inside his render function I wrote this code to setup 2 toggle button at the bottom :

```js
render() {
        return (
            <View style={this.style.container}>
                <View style={this.style.footer_container}>
                    <View style={this.style.left_container}></View>
                    <View style={this.style.right_container}></View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

and it's work

[image]

But now I want to add TouchableHighlight arround my 2 button like :

```
render() {
        return (
            <View style={this.style.container}>
                <View style={this.style.footer_container}>
                    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={"rgba(255, 0, 255,0)"} onPress={this.tooglePage}>
                        <View style={this.style.left_container}></View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={"rgba(255, 0, 255,0)"} onPress={this.tooglePage}>
                        <View style={this.style.right_container}></View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

and now my button are remplaced by this grey line...

[image]

What did I do wrong ? I got a TouchableHilight item just above these button that work perfectly...

This.style and this.togglePage are already set

Thanks on advance

PS : I'm using expo 43.0.3 with react native 0.64.3

PSS : As Vasyl Nahuliak requirement, I put the entire class here :

```
interface toggleFunction {
    togglePage: () => void
}
class Toggle_page extends Component<toggleFunction> {
    gongImage: ImageSourcePropType = {
        uri: "./gongImage.png"
    }

    state: {gongpage:boolean} = {
        gongpage:true
    }

    tooglePage() {
        alert("Toogle !")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={this.styles.container}>
                <View style={this.styles.footer_container}>
                    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={"rgba(255, 0, 255,0)"} onPress={this.tooglePage}>
                        <View style={this.styles.left_container}></View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={"rgba(255, 0, 255,0)"} onPress={this.tooglePage}>
                        <View style={this.styles.right_container}></View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    width:number = Dimensions.get("window").width;

    styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
        },
        footer_container: {
            flex:1,
            flexDirection: "row",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(87, 87, 87)",
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width
        },
        left_container: {
            backgroundColor: "white",
            flex:1,
        },
        right_container: {
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            flex:1
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Add `styles` code

Comment: To TouchableHighlight elements ?

Comment: `this.style` all style from here

Comment: I alredy set this.style

Comment: Please add code where you styles (code) into question. This helps to better answer.

Comment: All the class code is here now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add `flex: 1` for `TouchableHighlight`

```
  <View style={this.styles.container}>
    <View style={this.styles.footer_container}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor={'rgba(255, 0, 255,0)'}
        style={this.styles.button} // <--- add flex: 1
        onPress={this.tooglePage}>
        <View style={this.styles.left_container}></View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={this.styles.button} // <--- add flex: 1
        underlayColor={'rgba(255, 0, 255,0)'}
        onPress={this.tooglePage}>
        <View style={this.styles.right_container}></View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  </View>

  ...
  styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
      flex: 1,
    },
  ...
```

Live example here: https://snack.expo.dev/@vasylnahuliak/70908017-two-touchablehighlight

Comment: Oh perfect ! Thank you